# OpenShift: How to set the log-level of JBoss AS

Tags: logging, jboss7.x, openshift, jboss-eap-6

In OpenShift I want to set the log level of JBoss AS to "DEBUG".

In my local JBoss installation I can achieve this by editing the logging configuration in `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`.

The default level of the root-logger is "INFO", but when I set that to "DEBUG" and restart JBoss, then I have achieved my goal.

How can I acheve the same in OpenShift?
I can SSH into the OpenShift App and manually modify `jbossas/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`. However when I restart the App, all those changes are lost, and consequently the level of the root-logger is reset to "INFO".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this settings to be permanent you should add something to *.openshift/action_hooks/deploy* which applies this setting during deploy of the application. The hook is part of the git repo, so you can modify it locally and it gets executed during deployment. See also https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications.

You could use a perl one lines to do the modification. Something like this should do:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/<level name=\"INFO\"\/>/<level name=\"DEBUG\"\/>/g' <path-tp-standalone-xml>
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Actually I think this is quite cumbersome, but probably there is no better way.

Comment: What I will try to do is use a .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy hook and then use the JBoss CLI to switch the log level like this: 

./bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:change-root-log-level(level=DEBUG)"

Comment: Sure, you can use a post deploy hook as well. Really a matter of taste.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this isn't working for me.  The post commit hook was failing, it no longer is, I had to sleep 30 seconds for the jboss-cli --connect to work.